# How to use inheritance in .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to understand if possible and how to properly do inheritance in .gitlab-ci.yml file without overriding? Not sure if this practical at all though.
Example code below:

```yaml
.deploy_template_basic: &basic_deploy
  script:
    - npm install --global surge

.deploy_template: &deploy
  <<: *basic_deploy
  #include: basic_deploy
  cache: []
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - surge --project ./public --domain $DOMAIN
  environment:
    url: http://$DOMAIN

deploy review:
  <<: *deploy
  stage: deploy review
  variables:
    DOMAIN: random_name-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  only:
    - merge_requests
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    on_stop: stop review
  before_script:
    - echo -e "\033[1;35mStage began deploy review"

stop review:
  <<: *basic_deploy
  stage: deploy review
  only:
    - merge_requests
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - echo -e "\033[1;31mRemove review app"
  script:
    - surge teardown random_name-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
```

I want to establish chain of inheritance through templates (&basic_deploy -> &deploy -> job).

I tried `include` and `<<:`

Answer (score 0):

To have inheritance it is possible to use anchors or `extends` [keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html). But if you override one of the sections (for example `script`) in the extended job - this definition will be used. To inherit a job and extend without overriding - it is possible to use [!reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) keyword. Example with script:

```
.job-1:
  stage: doit
  script:
    - echo "job-1"

.job-2: # does not extend, just references 'script' section; will not inherit 'stage'
  script:
    - !reference [.job-1, script]
    - echo "job-2"

job-3: # extends and references 'script' section; will inherit 'stage'
  extends: .job-1
  script:
    - !reference [.job-1, script]
    - echo "job-3"
```